# Mostrar las letras de una cadena y cuantas hay

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql

Tengo un código que me muestra las letras de un un nombre y el número de letras que hay en ese nombre. Pero cuando me imprime las letras y cuantas hay, me repite las letras que ya leyó y me cuenta los espacios. Aquí el código:

```
create or REPLACE PROCEDURE nombre is
begin
    declare 
        nombre VARCHAR(100) := 'Pepito perez';
        letra VARCHAR(1);
        letra2 VARCHAR(1);
        contador int;                       
    begin 
        for i in 1..LENGTH(nombre) loop
            contador :=0;
            letra := SUBSTR(nombre, i, 1);
            for j in 1..LENGTH(nombre) loop
                letra2 := SUBSTR(nombre, j, 1);                 
                    if (letra2 = letra) then
                        contador := contador +1;
                    end if;

            end loop;
            begin
                dbms_output.put_line(letra||': '|| contador);
            end;
        end loop;   
    end;
end;
```

El resultado que arroja es:

```
SQL> exec nombre
p: 3
e: 3
p: 3
i: 1
t: 1
o: 1
: 1
p: 3
e: 3
r: 1
e: 3
z: 1
```

Lo que necesito es que solo muestre por ejemplo la `P` y cuantas hay, pero no que se repitan.

Comment: Creo que sería mejor que convirtieras el texto en array antes de recorrerlo.

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar a tu pregunta el resultado preciso esperado para tu ejemplo?

Comment: y si necesito identificar si son repetidos entre si o tambien son secuenciales me refiero a caracteres numericos del 0 al 9, como pueden ayudarme

Answer (score 2):

Para que no repita la letra y la cantidad que se encuentra en la cadena necesitamos saber si el carácter en cuestión ya fue impreso. Para ello vamos a hacer una función que averigua eso.

A la función lo llamaremos **letra_ya_mostrada**. La función recibirá tres argumentos:

1. letra: el carácter que deseamos averiguar si ya se imprimió.
2. nombre: la cadena de texto completa que estas analizando.
3. iter actual: la ubicación actual en donde se posiciona la letra en el bucle principal.

La tarea de la función es recorrer inversamente el nombre desde la ubicación que le pases por parámetro y averiguar si la letra que también recibís se encuentra en una ubicación anterior.

Ejemplo:

```
letra = 'p'
nombre = 'Pepito perez'
ubicacion = 3
```

La función analiza la porción 'Pe' de nombre de de la siguiente manera:

```
'e' = 'p'
'P' = 'p'
```

y si encuentra coincidencia asume que la letra ya se mostró en pantalla.

La función es como sigue:

```
function letra_ya_mostrada(
    i_letra     in varchar2, 
    i_nombre    in varchar2, 
    i_iter_actual in number
)  return varchar2 is

    mostrado varchar2(1) := 'N';

begin

    for i in reverse 1..i_iter_actual - 1 loop
        if ( UPPER(i_letra) = UPPER(SUBSTR(i_nombre, i, 1)) ) then
            mostrado := 'S';
        end if;
    end loop;

    return mostrado;

end;
```

Vamos a modificar el siguiente bloque para evaluar si la letra ya fue mostrada.

```
begin
    if letra_ya_mostrada(letra, nombre, i) = 'N' then
        dbms_output.put_line(letra||': '|| contador);
    end if;
end;
```

El procedimiento quedaría de la siguiente manera.

```
create or REPLACE PROCEDURE nombre is

    function letra_ya_mostrada(
        i_letra     in varchar2, 
        i_nombre    in varchar2, 
        i_iter_actual in number
    )  return varchar2 is

        mostrado varchar2(1) := 'N';

    begin

        for i in reverse 1..i_iter_actual - 1 loop
            if ( UPPER(i_letra) = UPPER(SUBSTR(i_nombre, i, 1)) ) then
                mostrado := 'S';
            end if;
        end loop;

        return mostrado;
    end;

begin

    declare 
        nombre VARCHAR(100) := 'Pepito perez';
        letra VARCHAR(1);
        letra2 VARCHAR(1);
        contador int;                       
    begin 
        for i in 1..LENGTH(nombre) loop
            contador :=0;
            letra := SUBSTR(nombre, i, 1);
            for j in 1..LENGTH(nombre) loop
                letra2 := SUBSTR(nombre, j, 1);                 
                    if (UPPER(letra2) = UPPER(letra)) then
                        contador := contador +1;
                    end if;

            end loop;

            begin
                if letra_ya_mostrada(letra, nombre, i) = 'N' then
                    dbms_output.put_line(letra||': '|| contador);
                end if;
            end;

        end loop;   
    end;

end;
```

Saludos!!